# Using sed to find a string in one file and replace with text in another file in Xcode

Tags: xcode, search, text, sed, replace

```
shell: /bin/tcsh
```

I'm attempting to search for a string in a Cocos2D tmx file and replace it with text from another file.

Before the touch commands in Run Script, I have the following:

```
sed -i '' 's{<tileset firstgid="1.*<layer name="background"{Resources/maps_sideScrolling/tileProperties.txt{g' Resources/maps_sideScrolling/ruinsItemCave2.tmx;
```

I'm fairly certain the file `ruinsItemCave2.tmx` is found, because if I change the file path I get an error when I build the project. As of now, `ruinsItemCave2.tmx` is not affected in any way.

Eventually I will want to change `ruinsItemCave2` to a wildcard filename so it affects every file name, though I'm not sure how to write `Resources/maps_sideScrolling/*.tmx` the proper way.

I also know that without even writing a file path of tileProperties.txt, but just writing "test" does nothing to my `ruinsItemCave2` file, so I can't even get that far as of now. Does it have to do with using `tcsh`?

Comment: Your example works here with GNU sed and BSD sed.

Comment: Does it have to do with my shell then? (/bin/tcsh)
It works fine if I'm not searching double quotes.

Comment: Actually it doesn't seem to have to do with the shell. I have a run script running sh before my other one that runs tcsh and it still doesn't work.  I've had double quotes work just fine in another project running sh.

Comment: I think I know what the real problem is: I'm searching a wildcard across multiple lines. How do I make this work?

Comment: This is a completely different question. Either rephrase your question or delete and ask a new one.

Comment: Okay I'll make a new question.

Comment: Here's the new one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14591375/find-and-replace-over-multiple-lines-using-sed-in-xcode-run-script-bin-sh