# Find and replace over multiple lines using sed in Xcode Run Script bin/sh

Tags: xcode, sed, replace, multiline, carriage-return

I have a Cocos2D tmx file which is very much like an xml and includes carriage returns and spaces.

**My requirements are:**

In every tmx file in Resources/maps_sideScrolling/

find and everything between

```
<tileset firstgid="1"
```

and the first occurring

```
<layer name="background"
```

and replace with the contents of Resources/maps_sideScrolling/tileProperties.txt

I've tried the following with no result.  The problem is caused by the string to be searched has multiple lines.

```
sed -i '' 's{<tileset firstgid="1.*<layer name="background"{Resources/maps_sideScrolling/tileProperties.txt{g' Resources/maps_sideScrolling/*.tmx;
```

Here's a pastebin of the tmx snippet that I want to edit: http://pastebin.com/wr39zj1r

Comment: upload a sample of such file somewhere, or even use a pastebin.com if it’s not that big.

Comment: Okay here http://pastebin.com/wr39zj1r  

Also edited my post to include pastebin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geek uses python to do this kind of thing to TMX map files.  Just an option to consider.

Something like this (but iterating all files in directory etc), and save it as a .sh file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re

#you'd open a file and read in the tile properties thing
fakeTileProperties = "<tileproperties>1</tileproperties>\r"

f = open( "file1.tmx", "rU")
fo = open( "outputfile.tmx", "wc");

#read source file
s = f.read();

#find what you need
m = re.search("([\W\w]*)(<tileset firstgid=\"1\"[\W\w]*)(<layer name=\"background\"[\W\w]*)", s )

#write out to source file
fo.write(m.group(1))
fo.write(fakeTileProperties)
fo.write(m.group(3));

f.close();
fo.close();

print "done!"
```

The code handles content before the tile set firstgid="1" just in case there is some.

To use a script like this in Xcode 4 do the following:

- put your script in a file next to your project file, name it `myscript.py`
- use `chmod +x myscript.py` to make the script file executable.
- in your Xcode project select the project and target and "Build Phases" tab and then create a new "Run Script" build phase.
- leave the default shell of /bin/sh
- put the following into the script field:  `$(SOURCE_ROOT)/myscript.py`

Then when you do a build you should see the python script get executed.  You can do a really simple test python file to test this (I just did):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

print 'hello from python!'
```

note that the setting in the Run Script setup "Show Environmental variables in build log" is very helpful for getting the environmental variables like `SOURCE_ROOT` and such to locate your files.

good luck!

Comment: Can I run this as a Run Script in Xcode? I'd like it to happen automatically every build.

Comment: definitely. put a shebang line as the first line in the file and name the file .sh and maybe chmod it to be executable and you should be good.  `#!/usr/bin/env python` as the first line.

Comment: I put the myScript.py in the same directory as my project file and did the chmod command, and put $(SOURCE_ROOT)/myScript.py in the run script console, and I get the error line 2: /myScript.py: No such file or directory. Note that I called mine myScript.py (with a capital S) both in the console and as the actual filename.

Comment: Looks like either you mistyped SOURCE_ROOT or it's not set.  Check the spelling.  If looks right, then turn on the `Show Environmental variables in build log` setting I mentioned above and check the value for SOURCE_ROOT and make sure it's pointing to where you .py file is.  Filename case must match but otherwise doesn't matter.  Spaces in the path or filename can also be an issue but the error doesn't indicate that (use quotes as appropriate if there are spaces in the path).

Comment: I found that the error was coming from not using brackets instead of parenthesis around SOURCE_ROOT.  Also, this solution seems to work for files in the root directory of my project, and not my resources.

Comment: Yes, SOURCE_ROOT points to the root and the fopen calls pass just the file name so they are looking for files in the current working directory which defaults to be the same as the script (or SOURCE_ROOT, not positive which).  You said you had sub-directory of files to work on and such so it's expected you'll be modifying this sample script. It was just designed to get you started not to write the exact code for you (you don't learn much that way).

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sed -rni '/<tileset\s+firstgid="1"/ {
s/(\s*<tileset\s+firstgid="1").*/\1/p
r /home/username/ololofile
:loop
n
s/.*<layer name="background".*/&/p
t
b loop
}' ~/files/to/replace/*
```

sed with `-n` option will output nothing until print (`p`) is forced or there is some file reading.

There were suddenly errors when I tried to run the script with comments, so deleted my post, but then figured out that *spaces* between the file name to read with `r` command and commentary are treated as continuation to the file name so I removed comments and will describe the script commands for sed line by line now:

1. look for a pattern to begin with;
2. at the second line useful part of the found line is printed out;
3. then goes reading from file;
4. next line contains label, since now we read and search line by
   line;
5. line matching the end pattern found and printed;
6. because we need only first matching end pattern, in case of a successful replace go to the end of the script;
7. if no replace was performed, there was no jump to the end and goes jump to `loop` label where a new line will attempt to load into the pattern space.

Comment: @vagueexplanation what version of sed (can be obtained via `sed --version`) are you using? Mine is GNU sed 4.2.1. In case of you're running sed coming with cygwin, it is probably too old.  

`-r` option stands for extended regular expression syntax. The code above may be adapted to old style regexp, but this will require more escaping in patterns — http://pastie.org/pastes/6082601/text  
But I’d recommend to use sed which supports more clean regexp syntax anyway.

Comment: I've been having a hard time finding the version. I'm using the one that comes with OS X Lion that's used in the Run Script command line in Xcode. I tried yours with editing, but get "unexpected EOF (pending }'s)" Here's my code to confirm: http://pastebin.com/qFLtxYau

Comment: I see four choises for you: a) write the code in one line dividing former lines with a semicolon — maybe that will help; b) trying to fix the code above further to be POSIX (or Apple) compliant, but I guarantee that will be a long way full of fun and amazing syntax forms; c) go to Apple tech support; d) install GNU sed http://solarianprogrammer.com/2012/03/07/starting-gnu-sed-mac-osx/

Comment: I installed GNU sed, and made the command all one line and I get sed: 1: "/<tileset\s\+firstgid=" ...": bad flag in substitute command: 'r'

Comment: There is probably missing semicolon between `p` from substitution and `r` from reading the file.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat file1
abc
def
ghi

$ cat file2
pre
stuff
<tileset firstgid="1"
foo
bar
<layer name="background"
post
stuff

$ awk '
   NR==FNR { s=s ORS $0; next }
   /<tileset firstgid="1"/    { print $0 s; f=1 }
   /<layer name="background"/ { f=0 }
   !f
' file1 file2
pre
stuff
<tileset firstgid="1"
abc
def
ghi
<layer name="background"
post
stuff
```

Note the above replaces foo\nbar in file2 with the contents of file1 based on the delimiters you wanted. If you want to remove the delimiting lines too, that's a trivial tweak.

Comment: Upon building, it gives me tons of Shell Script Invocation Errors "command not found" and "No such file or directory on things like "tileset" and "layer"

Comment: @VagueExplanation - look, this script is trivial and simply works. If it failed for you then it's something wrong with the way you're calling it or your data or something else you haven't shared with us yet so cat the file the script is in and copy/paste the output of that plus the terminal display of you running the command and the specific error message you get and update your posted question with that info so we can help you further.

Comment: The first pastebin shows the sample input, the command and it running correctly. The second pastebin shows a bunch of error messages that appear to be the result of executing a file named "Script-84A160B416B83E2100C7987A.sh" which you don't show us the contents of but kinda look like you were trying to execute the output of the awk command. You CAN see that the awk command works in your first pastebin right? We'd need to know what that ".sh" file contains that's producing the error messages in your second pastebin to help you more - THAT is what's failing, not the awk script.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way using `sed`. Run like:

```
sed -f script.sed Resources/maps_sideScrolling/*.tmx
```

Contents of `script.sed`:

```
/<tileset firstgid="1"/ {

    s/\(<tileset firstgid="1"\).*/\1/

    r Resources/maps_sideScrolling/tileProperties.txt

    p

    :a
    N
    s/.*\(<layer name="background".*\)/\1/
    t
    ba
}
```

Please let me know how it goes. I don't have access to a machine with `BSD sed` at the moment so I haven't been able to test it properly. However, my gut feeling is that it should work for you.

Comment: I have not tried the GNU sed, but the BSD/OSX one replaces everything after and including <tileset firstgid="1" with the literal text string Resources/maps_sideScrolling/tileProperties.txt

Comment: ...and not the contents of the .txt file.

Comment: Thank you, but the script has no effect. I assured the location of script.sed was correct (in Resources/maps_sideScrolling/).  I found a discrepancy between the .* in the <tileset firstgid="1" firstgid and the <layer name="background". Could this be part of the problem?

Comment: @vagueexplanation I’d suggest to check the man (or maybe better info) page of sed of yours, cause I’m in doubt if it actually supports file reading.